# Problem downloading Drupal with Drush - tmp directory?

Tags: 7, drush

I'm relatively new to Drush, but I have used it to download Drupal many times. Today, I'm getting the following error when I try to download Drupal to my local MAMP environment:

```
copy(/tmp/drush_tmp_1383508894_5276ab9ec3885/drupal): 
failed to open stream: No such file or directory             [warning]
filesystem.inc:235
 Project drupal (7.23) could not be downloaded to /Users/timerickson/htdocs/drupal.
```

I can't find any basic info on the tmp directory. Where is this directory supposed to be? How do I best resolve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers :) This is a known bug that came up as a result of the Drupal.org upgrade last week. Please follow the [issue on github](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/issues/234) for more details as we can't deal with bug reports here

Comment: Sorry, I looked for other reports and didn't find them. Thanks.

Comment: No problem, this happened to me too yesterday and it's so fundamental I didn't even think to check the issue queue - I just assumed that particular install of Drush was knackered :)

Comment: You can use wget to download drupal for now.
I am also facing the same issue, all other commands are working fine like downloading modules and updates etc..